# How to efficiently grow a Matrix?

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics

[Using Math.NET Numerics library]

I have a method where I am adding an unknown amount of rows to a `Matrix<double>`. What is the fastest, most efficient way to grow the Matrix? Anything better than:

```
Matrix<double> origDb = Matrix.Build.Dense(22, 22);
...
int additionalRows = 22;
Matrix<double> newDb = Matrix.Build.Dense(origDb.RowCount + additionalRows, origDb.ColumnCount);
newDb.SetSubMatrix(0, 0, origDb);
origDb = newDb;
```

?

Comment: This question is about `MathNET.Numerics` optimizations, and not native `C#` arrays, correct?

Comment: @JAlex yes, correct. Edited question for clarification.

Comment: There is no fastest most efficient way. You either start with one larger then you need (the fastest), Or you need to allocate more memory and copy every time it needs to grow.. Usually more than you need, to make it more efficient for future growth. So this question likely comes down to the fastest way way to copy a matrix to a new larger matrix. Since multi dimensional arrays are stored in a linear contagious array, You will likely need to copy it row by row :/

Comment: For native arrays, you can use loops, `Array.Copy()` or `Buffer.Copy()` the last one being the fastest. But for `MathNET` library, I am not sure anyone can answer effectively because it depends on the developers of the library and not the end-user.